# What convergency test can be applied to this serie?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to apply a convergency test to

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^4}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^3}{(n-1)!}$$

I can't seem to figure if any comparison test apply; those that I tried gave no useful information. Any ideas?

Comment: What comparison tests do you know? Which ones did you try to apply? What was the difficulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much more natural to use the quotient test here:$$\frac{\frac{(n+1)^4}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{n^4}{n!}}=\frac{(n+1)^4}{(n+1)n^4}=\frac{(n+1)^3}{n^4}\to0.$$

Comment: That is completely reasonable. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I know this is not the case, but what happens if the ratio tends to infinity? Can we say, since $\infty>1$ $(?)$, that the serie diverges?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You can get rid of the numerator with $$n^3=(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)+6(n-1)(n-2)+7(n-1)+1$$

and your sum has the general term

$$\frac1{(n-4)!}+6\frac1{(n-3)!}+7\frac1{(n-2)!}+\frac1{(n-1)!}.$$

You should see the connection to the constant $e$. Also note that for $n>2,n!>\,2^{n-1}$.

Comment: (+1) I was thinking of this same approach.

Answer (score 0):

For a comparison-based method, note that $\frac{n^4}{n!}<\frac{n^4}{(n-5)^6}\leq\frac{2^6}{n^2}$ for $n\geq 10$.